# How to open an url in Firefox via cron (cron jobs scheduling)

Tags: cron

Am trying to create a cron job to open a web page at a scheduled time.

I have edited my cron using `crontab -e` and append my job. 
I wrote my job in a script like this: `xdg-open (URL)` 
I saved this script in my `/home/flicker` directory.

However, when I edit my cron (`crontab -e`), it saves the file as `/tmp/crontab.tIzXBv/crontab`.

After saving it successfully says installing new crontab.

I made my file script executable, but still failing to handle the job. 
I wanted the script to run at 14:30PM, so I added this line to my crontab:

```
30 14 * * * /home/flicker/open-web.sh
```

This is still failing to work please help. Here is my script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdg-open https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Are you setting the display in your script `export DISPLAY=:0`?  Also, what exactly is failing, nothing happens, or you get an error?

Comment: @bc2946088, an not get any error, nothing happens, I want it to open in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Does your script work if you run it manually from Terminal?

Comment: Please add your entire script to your base-post/question above

Comment: @dufte, the script works when I run it manually

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to execute a bash script via cron i would use

```
30 14 * * * /bin/bash /home/flicker/open-web.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

To call a web page/URL via cron & curl

```
30 14 * * * /usr/bin/curl  http://funkyname.com/blub.html >/dev/null 2>&1
```

## Update:

After realizing you want to open an actual browser and NOT just calling a script - i guess i understood your case.

You can solve that without bash script - instead write all logic directly to your crontab.

**for Chrome:**

```
30 14 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && google-chrome --new-window http://www.randomurl.com
```

**for Firefox:**

```
30 14 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && firefox --new-window http://www.randomurl.com
```

**Keep in mind:**

The `--new-window` parameter is forcing the browser in charge to open a new window, if you don't want that, just remove that section.

To avoid *noise output* you can optional add `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of your cron entry.

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestions, unfortunately it didn't work still.

Comment: updated my post,  tested it - is working now

Comment: Wow! wow! @dufte, thanks alot, your update answer,  it has worked, thanks alot

Comment: Glad to hear it finally worked out for you

Comment: when removing the `--new-window` firefox fails to open because is already running... I would like to open in a new tab. It works fine if called directly on terminal, but not as cron job. Firefox message: __Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile.__